# Show items from last week in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

In git I can use time modifiers to find all the commits made last week, for example:

```git
git log --all --pretty='%C(auto)%h %cd %d' --date=short --since='last week' --until='this week'
```

When building a query in Azure DevOps I can set a number of days in the past, as in this example:

[image: Azure DevOps Query Builder screenshot showing @StartOfDay('-7d') etc.]

But 'last week' is not a set number of days ago. Today, Monday, last week might mean anything in the seven day period ending one day ago, while tomorrow, Tuesday, last week would mean anything in the seven day period ending two days ago, etc. Is there a way in Azure DevOps query builder to match the English usage of the phrase "last week" in the same way I can in git?

Comment: Do you need work items that created in the last week?

Comment: Exactly (though I'm actually after the ones closed last week, I swapped to 'created date' to test the query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation [Query by date or current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops) I realise that I get exactly what I want by specifying

```
Created Date < @StartOfWeek
Created Date > @StartOfWeek('-1w')
```

or the simpler

```
Created Date < @StartOfWeek
Created Date > @StartOfWeek - 1
```

There are additional examples listed in the WIQL syntax documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops#start-of)